# Firefox (Opera) max-height without setting height for parent

Tags: html, firefox, css

I have the following structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="image">
        <div class="child-2"></div>
        <div class="child-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`container` has fixed height and width.

It's responsive design, so the image will scale to fit inside of `container` with `max-height` and `max-width` set to 100%.
 
`child-1` and `child-2` need to be positioned on top of the image at specific spots. To achieve that, I made `wrapper` have `max-height` and `max-width` of 100% too, so it wraps itself around the image. Then I can place `child-1` and 2 relative to `wrapper`.
In WebKit, it works beautifully, in FF and Opera however, it doesn't. They don't respect the max- at all.

Answer (score 0):

Per spec, if `<div class="wrapper">` has auto height, then a percentage max-height on its children should behave the same way as `auto` max-height.  Sounds like FF and Opera are following the spec and WebKit is not...

Comment: Ah, brilliant. I hate CSS. Always feels like driving a car that can't do left turns. Yes, three right turns accomplish the same, but still...